# Download an Image via API (Pexels)

Tags: python, image, api, download, python-requests

Documentation - [link](https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation)

I want to download an image via API. The code runs without errors, but it doesn't download anything. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
photo_request_link = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/photos/'
photo_id = {'id':102152}
f = open('00000001.jpeg','wb')
f.write(requests.get(photo_request_link,headers = {'Authorization':api_key},data=photo_id).content)
f.close()
```

Comment: Which library are you using exactly? Could you please share the github link.

Comment: Just the import requests.